# Should the internal request be sent to api-gateway in microservices architecture?

Tags: microservices, latency, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I am creating a microservice architecture.

Suppose I have three services: alpha, beta, gamma

and suppose the end-user sends a request to alpha and the structure is such that the alpha needs to send a request to beta and beta to gamma.

user <===> alpha  <===> beta <===> gamma

I also have a kong API gateway so actually, the user sends the request to kong and kong dispatches it the service requested by the user.

The question is, should the internal requests also go through kong or not?

user <===> ***kong*** <===> alpha  <===> beta <===> gamma

OR

user <===> ***kong*** <===> alpha <===> ***kong***  <===> beta <===> ***kong*** <===> gamma

Note that one of the benefits of using kong is its plugins. For example, if I want to use the `correlation-id` or `Zipkin` plugin and trace requests and latency in all the internal services, I need to reach them through kong. But my concern is, doesn't it add latency to the whole system? Is it a recommended practice in microservices architecture or not?

Comment: My vision on API: You should not care of the microservice topology, you should think API. When a call is done this shouldn't be done to a specific microservice but to an API. Then the API GW is in charge to reach the right origin. This is key to avoid strong coupling.

Comment: OPTION#1 is better design. For internal call, adding API GW is too much dependency on external tools and latency.  You can always add correlation-id with light plugin like sleuth spring framework

Comment: Are there multiple beta and gamma instances?

Comment: probably. not decided yet. The deployment is based on ocp and ci/cd is with jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid strong coupling. Please invest some time in good API design , not with the backend in mind. For me the architecture idea looks somehow like a workflow with an Api gateway in it. You can also think about a compositioning service where the gateway knows this upstream and "the magic" with calling several other apis happens in this service. In this case you won't use the gateway as an esb. The only plugin you will really need is correlation-id.

Comment: can you please explain more, and provide examples to support your argument?

Comment: Please have a look at this explanation of a API composition pattern, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/modernization-data-persistence/api-composition.html. Please adapt this to your micro service scenario.